# nginx err_connection_refused, can anyone help me?

Tags: php, nginx, webserver

I installed my old site with PHP, MySQL and so on, an everything work fine, but my site is not reachable from the outside of my LAN. I did a ton of changes and tried at least 100 config for my nginx sites-enabled and PHP 7.4, but nothing helped me out. Either I get a 502 or connection refused error. My site is running on Ubuntu 20.04

Check this default container:

```
server {
    listen 80; 
    root /var/www; 
    index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
        
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;  
            #fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

And the php www.conf (tested both):

```
...
;listen = /var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock
listen = 0.0.0.0:9000
...
```

netstat -lntp:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9194/php-fpm: maste 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1086/mysqld         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9151/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      795/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      900/cupsd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1038/tor            
tcp6       0      0 :::33060                :::*                    LISTEN      1086/mysqld         
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      900/cupsd
```

Do you have any hints, something that I could have missed?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Questions about managing your servers can be asked on [sf]. In the future, similar questions should be asked there.

Answer (score 0):

Configure a file with error log, like:

```
server {
error_log /path/server.error.log;

listen 80; 
root /var/www; 
index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
server_name local...
```

Then, restart nginx and check the server.error.log file.
With these changes, you can give an idea of what is happening,

Comment: thank for your reply. already got my error log, no hints no ideas

2020/08/28 23:05:58 [emerg] 9103#9103: "fastcgi_index" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:30
2020/08/28 23:06:29 [emerg] 9112#9112: host not found in upstream "php-fpm" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:26
2020/08/29 01:37:46 [emerg] 8934#8934: open() "/path/server.error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like nginx don't see yuor php-fpm so, FIND php-fpm on harddisk and try put the pass into nginx.conf as fastcgi_pass to make it looks like:
`fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php/php7.*-fpm.sock;`

Comment: at the beginning i said it's running on ubuntu 20.04 (desktop vers. on my laptop)
my problem is i can visit the webserver if there only .html files, but i can not run php files

if i visit der webserver in my lan with other device than my localhost, the local ip changes automatically to localhost and i get the error refused error

Comment: thanks for still trying giving me support. The main problem is, i did set up the php and nginx part correctly, but the files: php7.4-fpm.sock & php-fpm.sock in the DIR are empty (0 Bytes). I should use the php7.4-fpm.sock, right?

it's this only thing, nginx redirect me to 'localhost' if i try to visit it from the own local ip. Except this, everything work perfectly. It drives slowly crazy!!!! man, i can record a vid..

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/php7.*-fpm.log
ngnix.conf => php-fpm socet?
location ~ \.php$ {
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;
include fastcgi_params;
}
```

https://saribzhanov.ru/tehno/nastraivaem-rabotu-php-fpm-na-port-ili-na-soket/
ocation / {
...

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    ...

    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

}
BUT

## netstat -tulpn | grep 9000

...
/etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf => listen = 127.0.0.1:9000

/etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf => listen = /var/run/fastcgi.sock

listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1 => uncoment

and in nginx.conf
location / {
...

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    ....

    fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

}
take a look at "fastcgi_pass"
nginx.conf
location / {
fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock; //127.0 replace with php7.*-fpm.sock ! looks like nginx don`t see yuor php-fpm

Comment: thanks for your reply, got still a 502 error

what do you mean with
-> ngnix.conf => php-fpm socet ?

Comment: can you please post the final > location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) { < ?, for me it's a lil bit confusing...